# WinForm WebBrowser called from WPF MainWindowLoad();DocumentLoadComplted fired after MainWindowLoad

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

I need to obtain some information from a webpage and display the same on the MainWindow. I am calling a routine written in a separate library whose properties provide these information to,once the webPage is loaded.

I have looked around a lot on stackoverflow and found various solutions;but none worked for me.Here is my routine:

```
protected System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb;
        public void ObtainProfileInformation()
        {
            url = CUSTOMER_PROFILE_URL;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                var th = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
                {
                    wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser() { Visible = false, ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true };
                    wb.DocumentCompleted += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        string target_url = wb.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                        if ((target_url.Contains("login") == false))
                        {
                            var html_text = wb.DocumentText;
                            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument html_document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                            html_document.LoadHtml(html_text);
                            foreach (var MatchingDiv in html_document.DocumentNode.Descendants("span"))
                            {
                                if (MatchingDiv.Id.Contains("lblFullName"))
                                {
                                    CustomerName = MatchingDiv.InnerText;
                                }
                                if (MatchingDiv.Id.Contains("lblCompany"))
                                {
                                    CompanyName = MatchingDiv.InnerText;
                                }
                                if (MatchingDiv.Id.Contains("lblTitle"))
                                {
                                    CustomerTitle = MatchingDiv.InnerText;
                                }
                                if (MatchingDiv.Id.Contains("lblEmail"))
                                {
                                    CustomerEmail = MatchingDiv.InnerText.Split(new char[] { ':' })[1].TrimStart();
                                }
                                if (MatchingDiv.Id.Contains("lblUsername"))
                                {
                                    CustomerUserName = MatchingDiv.InnerText.Split(new char[] { ':' })[1].TrimStart();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread();
                    };
                    wb.Navigate(url);
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
                });
                th.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
                th.Start();
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                wb.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                wb.Dispose();
                throw new Exception("Something strange", ex);
            }
        }
```

DocumentCompleted event is getting fired and the properties CustomerName etc. are getting filled but after the load event of the Window is completed.So i am unable to change them on the Window.

Comment: You need to do it upon `window.onload` event, example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19283143/1768303

Comment: Looks familiar, my version was readable.  You'll have to call th.Join() to wait for the results to be available.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks,was able to obtain my desired reults